# No Space left on device with dask

Tags: python, merge, dask

I have two very large databases called Network (800MB) and SecondOrder (33GB) and wanna perform a series of merges like this:

```
NetworkDD = dd.from_pandas(Network, npartitions=Network['NiuSup'].nunique())

NodesSharingSupplier = dd.merge(NetworkDD, NetworkDD, on='NiuSup').query('NiuCust_x != NiuCust_y')

### WORKS UNTIL HERE

NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.drop('NiuSup', axis=1)
NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.drop_duplicates()


NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.rename(columns={"NiuCust_x": "NiuSup", "NiuCust_y": "NiuCust"})

NodesSharingSupplier.to_csv("NodesSharingSupplier.csv")

NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.drop('NiuSup', axis=1)
NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.drop_duplicates()

NodesSharingSupplier=NodesSharingSupplier.rename(columns={"NiuCust_x": "NiuSup", "NiuCust_y": "NiuCust"})

SecondOrder=pd.read_csv("/home/francesco.serti/SecondOrder_line55.csv")
SecondOrderDD = dd.from_pandas(SecondOrder, npartitions=SecondOrder['NiuSup'].nunique())

SecondOrderDD_all = SecondOrderDD.merge(NodesSharingSupplier, on=['NiuCust','NiuSup'], how='left', indicator=True)
SecondOrderDD=SecondOrderDD_all.loc[SecondOrderDD_all._merge=='left_only',SecondOrderDD_all.columns!='_merge']

del SecondOrder
del NodesSharingSupplier

##HERE IF I DO .compute() an OS Error: No Space left on Device
SecondOrderDD.to_csv('/home/francesco.serti//SecondOrderDD_line75.csv', single_file=True)
```

I know that Dask operates in a lazy mode. I tried both to make all the computations in a lazy mode and then save it with .to_csv and to perform the .compute() immediately but in any case (maybe due to temp files generation?) I get a No Space left on Device error.
Is there a fix to this (e.g. force dask not to generate temp)? I even performed it on a server and the same error occurred!